# How to anchor QGraphicsView to a special point on a scene?

Tags: qt, qt4

**How to anchor QGraphicsView to a special point on a scene?**

I want a center of a *view* is anchored to the *scene* point (0,0).

But as said in docummentation:

> If the whole scene is visible in the
>   view, (i.e., there are no visible
>   scroll bars,) the view's alignment
>   will decide where the scene will be
>   rendered in the view.

And if I set agnment to Qt::AlignCenter *view* becomes anchored to the *scene* center.

Is it possibe to do?

I need something like QGraphicsView::centerOn that always put the point in to the view center.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can *anchor* a QGraphicsView at a specific position by defining ("forcing") its *sceneRect* property, other than the default one (i.e. QGraphicsScene bounding rectangle).

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html#sceneRect-prop

Here is a code example. The *view* is centered at point(0,0), no mather the bounding rect scene or centerOn function.

```
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QGraphicsEllipseItem>
#include <QDebug>

//...

QGraphicsScene scene;
QGraphicsView view(&scene);

QRect viewRect(-100, -100, 200, 200);
view.setSceneRect(viewRect);
qDebug() << viewRect.center(); //QPointF(0,0)

scene.addEllipse(-5,-5,10,10);
qDebug() << scene.sceneRect(); //QRectF(-5,-5 10x10)
scene.addRect(QRectF(0, 0, 200, 200));
qDebug() << scene.sceneRect(); //QRectF(-5,-5 205x205)

view.show();

view.centerOn(QPointF(50, 50)); //nothing happens!
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the [`alignment property`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qgraphicsview.html#alignment-prop) to achieve this.

Comment: With AlignmentCenter the whole scene will be centered in the view. But not some special point.

Comment: When you speak about special point, you are speaking about points of QGraphicsItem in the scene? As far as I am concerned it's not possible for the view to manage the objects inside the scene.

Comment: Try switching the scrollbars off using setVerticalScrollBarPolicy ( Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff ) and the same for horizontal as well. If you still have problems, try making sure the scene is always bigger than the view area.

Comment: "try making sure the scene is always bigger than the view area" I think that's impossible because you always can zoom out so that the scene will be smaller.