# Qt fitInView and resizing

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to make a `QGraphicsView` with same width as height positioned in center of the window.

I created a ordinary `QGraphicsView` in Qt Designer and set minimal size, added some calculations that center the `QGraphicsView` into center of the main window and that set the same width as height. It uses only `setGeometry`. Than I created a `QGraphicsScene` with only one very long rectangle. I want the graphics scene to fit to view so I have used `QGraphicsView::fitInView`. Everything works OK, but the problem cames with resizing window.

When I increase height and width of the window everything also works fine. The `QGraphicsView` has a new position and a new size. When I reduce only a part of size of the window everything still works fine. But (finally) when I reduce the size of window to the possible minimum everything breaks. The rectangle in view has the right width (the same as without resizing, I have measured it with a ruler :) ), but a new margin is created and also `QGraphicsView` is not positioned and sized right (so it is not only the margin, but maybe also the `setGeometry` has no effect).

I have noticed, that the same thing happens when I call `QGraphicsView::fitInView` before using `setGeometry`.

It is getting me crazy, please help!

Here is some code:

```
void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *e)
{
    int h = e->size().height(),
        w = e->size().width(),
        s;

    if(w > h) s = h-120;
    else s = w-120;

    ui->board->setGeometry((w-s)/2,(h-s)/2,s,s);

    int scaleWidth = ui->board->scene()->width(),
        scaleHeight = ui->board->scene()->height();

    ui->board->fitInView(QRectF(0, 0, scaleWidth, scaleHeight), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);

}
```

Here are images of what happens to `QGraphicsView`, the rectangle is red, view is blue:

[image: this is OK]
[image: this is broken]

Comment: The documentation for fitInView states '...rect must be inside the scene rect; otherwise, fitInView() cannot guarantee that the whole rect is visible.' Can you print out the values for scaleWidth & scaleHeight when the desired output does not occur and check them relative to the scene?

Comment: The scaleWidth and scaleHeight are same in both cases. They are as large as the inserted rectangle.

Comment: "if(w > h) s = h-120; else s = w-120;" Can you please explain what you're doing here and why you've got a hard-coded value of 120? If it relates to other code, please include that in your question.

Comment: It has no relation to other code. It is there because of "margin". You can see this gap on the left or top side in the images. It has no importance there.

Comment: +1: Thanks for the valuable observation "when I call QGraphicsView::fitInView before using setGeometry"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was trying to use `QGraphicsView::fitInView` with `Qt::KeepAspectRatio,` and was running into similar issues.
I found this answer helpful:

[How to anchor QGraphicsView to a special point on a scene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022907/how-to-anchor-qgraphicsview-to-a-special-point-on-a-scene)

It seems the key is to manually set the scene's bounding rectangle. The following code worked for me:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : 
    QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Set up graphics view
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    drawMyWidget();
    scene->setSceneRect(-1.25, -1.25, 2.5, 2.5);    // your scene's bounding rect here...
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    ui->graphicsView->show();
}

void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *) {
    QRectF bounds = scene->itemsBoundingRect();
    bounds.setWidth(bounds.width()*0.9);         // to tighten-up margins
    bounds.setHeight(bounds.height()*0.9);       // same as above
    ui->graphicsView->fitInView(bounds, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
    ui->graphicsView->centerOn(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the same thing but in a DialogForm...

I defined the Class header like this

```
#ifndef MAP_H
#define MAP_H

#include <QDebug>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QImage>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
namespace Ui {
class Map;
}

class Map : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Map(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Map();

private:
    Ui::Map *ui;
    QPixmap *m;         // This will load the Original Image
    QGraphicsScene* scene;  // This is the object passed to the Graphics Viewer
    QPixmap *scaledImage;  // This is the Scaled Image. It is created each resize from the Original Image (m)
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *);

};

#endif // MAP_H
```

The Dialog Form is very simple and looks like this, it is a GraphicsView with OK/Cancel button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Map</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Map">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>675</width>
    <height>486</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="QGraphicsView" name="graphicsView"/>
   </item>
   <item>
    <widget class="QDialogButtonBox" name="buttonBox">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="standardButtons">
      <set>QDialogButtonBox::Cancel|QDialogButtonBox::Ok</set>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections>
  <connection>
   <sender>buttonBox</sender>
   <signal>accepted()</signal>
   <receiver>Map</receiver>
   <slot>accept()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>248</x>
     <y>254</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>157</x>
     <y>274</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>buttonBox</sender>
   <signal>rejected()</signal>
   <receiver>Map</receiver>
   <slot>reject()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>316</x>
     <y>260</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>286</x>
     <y>274</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
 </connections>
</ui>
```

The Implementation of the class is like this....

```
#include "map.h"
#include "ui_map.h"

Map::Map(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Map)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    QWidget::setMouseTracking(true);

    m = new QPixmap ("/usr/local/share/pixmaps/gpredict/maps/nasa-topo_1600.jpg");
}

Map::~Map()
{
    delete m;
    delete scene;
    delete ui;
}

void Map::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *)
{
    qInfo() << "Resize event occurred";
    QSize gvs  = ui->graphicsView->size();
    QSize mvs  =  m->size();   // Just for interest

    qInfo() << "About to scale";
    qInfo() << "mvs is " << mvs;
    qInfo() << "gvs is " << gvs;
    QPixmap scaled_img = m->scaled(gvs, Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio);

    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    scene->addPixmap(scaled_img);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);


}
```

The Image is now resized whenever the dialogForm is resized. It is (importantly) resampled from the original image, else there could be a loss of image quality.

I am only on day 2 of QT programming - trying to get my head around how it is wired up, but I hope this helps someone.