# QT QGraphicsView How to set proper size of contents on resize?

Tags: c++, qt, video

[image: original video]

I have a video, which, as you can see, has no side borders. I want to play this video using `QGraphicsVideoItem` inserted in `QGraphicsScene` of `QGraphicsView`

Here's my init code:

```
_item = new QGraphicsVideoItem();

_scene = new QGraphicsScene();

_graphicsView = new QGraphicsView();
_graphicsView->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
_graphicsView->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
_graphicsView->setScene(_scene);
_graphicsView->scene()->setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QColor(0x00, 0x00, 0xF0)));
_graphicsView->scene()->addItem(_item);

_player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
_player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:/Temp/Black.avi"));
_player->setVideoOutput(_item);
_player->setPosition(0);
_player->pause();
```

When video is done loading I do this

```
_graphicsView->fitInView(_scene->itemsBoundingRect(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
```

Same goes for `resizeEvent(QResizeEvent*)`

So, remember I said video has no side borders?

[image: SUDDENLY, BORDERS!]

**SUDDENLY** in QT's opinion it has. WHY? How do I get rid of those things? I've looked up for documentation, and everything I tried didn't work.

```
qDebug() << "***";
qDebug() << _graphicsView->sceneRect();
qDebug() << _scene->itemsBoundingRect();
qDebug() << _scene->sceneRect();
qDebug() << _item->boundingRect();
qDebug() << "***";
```

all those rects contain SAME values

```
***
QRectF(0,13.3333 320x213.333)
QRectF(0,13.3333 320x213.333)
QRectF(0,13.3333 320x213.333)
QRectF(0,13.3333 320x213.333)
***
```

Not even a single of them match to original video size (which is 720x480) and none of them tell me any information about at which point the video itself positioned (I need this info to be able to draw some analytical data over it).

So, how do I resize video correctly, and how do I get a correct video rect in view?

**UPD:**

I've done some research and it turned out that file metadata could be wroung. Metadata says the video resolution is 720x480, but when I measured it myself the video turned out to be 640x480. Don't know why, and don't know how Windows Media Player handles those differences to show it correctly. Please, tell me if you have any thoughts how to get correct video size.

Still, struggling with finding correct position of video inside the view.

Comment: Have you tried this way: _graphicsView->fitInView(_graphicsView->sceneRect(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);

Comment: Yes. Same result

Comment: Thank maybe it adds borders in order to keep the aspect ratio? Or maybe you should use scene->setSceneRect when resizing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789878/qt-fitinview-and-resizing

Comment: I've done some research and it turned out that file metadata could be wroung. Metadata says the video resolution is 720x480, but when I measured it myself the video turnedout to be 640x480. Don't know why, and don't know how Windows Media Player handles those differences to show it correctly. Still, struggling with finding correct position of video inside the scene.

Comment: Some video files change their native resolution after the start of the playback. You might need to check the native resolution in mediaStatusChanged event, by accessing the metadata "Resolution" propety. Or you might try to use QGraphicsVideoItem and inspect its nativeSize property.